# Is the set of $x$ such that the series $\sum\frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$ converges, bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is the following set bounded :

$\{x\in \Bbb R:\sum _{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$ is convergent $ \}$.

I found the expansion of $\sum _{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$ is nothing but $\sin x$ but I could not figure out how would that help to figure that the set is bounded or not.

Any help will be helpful.

Comment: What do you call the set of all $x$ where a power series converges? What does it mean that this set is bounded?

Comment: The most direct route is to determine the set itself (since this set is especially simple). Let $x$ denote some real number, does the series $\sum\frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$ converge or not?

Comment: the ratio test should help us out here, right?

Comment: this is the sum for $\sin(x)$

Answer (score 3):

You just have to determine the radius of convergence of this series. The ratio of (the absolute values of) two consecutive coefficients is $\;\dfrac1{(2n+2)(2n+3)}$, which tends to $0$. Hence the radius of convergence is $+\infty$, i.e. the set is $\mathbf R$.