# How to determine the values of $x$ such that the series converge $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Here's the series:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$
How to determine the values of $x$ such that the series converge?

Comment: use the ratio test.

Comment: Fun fact: This is the power series of $\sin x$.

Comment: See also: [Is the set of $x$ such that the series $\sum\frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$ converges, bounded?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1633123).

Answer (score 0):

The ratio/root test is the standard technique. Also one can remember the exponencial's Taylor series:
$$ e^{z}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{k}}{k!}$$
Since $e^{z}$ is entire, the above series converges in $\mathbb{C}$. Then,
$$\frac{e^{z}-e^{-z}}{2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$
converges in $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 0):

here to find that for what values of x the given series converges 
you can use the ratio test as 
$$Lim\inf \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$$
that here becomes 
$$Lim\inf((\frac{-1^(n+1)(x)^(2n+3)}{(2n+3)!})(\frac{(2n+1)!}{(-1)^(n)(x)^(2n+1)!})$$
That is equal to zero,
this means that given series is convergent for all values of x

Comment: The expression could be simplified as lim(x^2/(2n+1)(2n+2)). The nominator is x, and the denominator is (2n+1)(2n+2). How do you know it is equal to zero without knowing the value of x?

Comment: @user214969 :The denominator contain 4n^2 and limit of n approaches to infinity 
and you that something divide by infinity gives zero
so that's why iam saying that it will give zero for all real value of x